# Windows Command Line Batch Variable Substring with WMIC Output not Truncating Properly

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, environment-variables

Using Windows Batch all I want to do is get the specified drive size in MB (by drive letter) and corresponding free space available for that drive stored in a variable as an integer to do some basic math.

I use this script:

```
for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %%x in (`wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='Z:'" get Size /format:value`) do
 set SizeDisk=%%x

for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %%x in (`wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='Z:'" get FreeSpace /format:value`) do
 set FreeS=%%x
```

This gives me the values I want. However, when I go to truncate the last six digits to give me MB (it's close enough for my needs):

```
SET /A SizeDiskMB=%SizeDisk:~0,-6%

SET /A FreeSMB=%FreeS:~0,-6%
```

It only truncates the last five digits not six. If I use `~0,-7` then it give me proper values, but I'd like to understand why it does this. I also need these as integer values so I can do some basic math which is the reason for the `/A`.

Thanks for any assistance.

**EDIT:**

OK, I realize I don't need the /A until I actually do the math. I thought it would set the variable as an integer, doesn't seem to be the case. So ignore that for now.

I ran the following code:

```
@ECHO OFF
cls

for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%x in (`wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='Z:'" get Size /format:value`) do set SizeDisk=%%x

Echo Size Disk:        %SizeDisk%   bytes
Echo Size Disk 0,-1:   %SizeDisk:~0,-1%
Echo Size Disk 0,-2:   %SizeDisk:~0,-2%
Echo Size Disk 0,-3:   %SizeDisk:~0,-3% KB
Echo Size Disk 0,-4:   %SizeDisk:~0,-4%
Echo Size Disk 0,-5:   %SizeDisk:~0,-5%
Echo Size Disk 0,-6:   %SizeDisk:~0,-6% MB
Echo Size Disk 0,-7:   %SizeDisk:~0,-7%

Pause
```

And received the following results:

```
Size Disk:        1887436795904 bytes <-- Same
Size Disk 0,-1:   1887436795904       <-- Same
Size Disk 0,-2:   188743679590
Size Disk 0,-3:   18874367959   KB
Size Disk 0,-4:   1887436795
Size Disk 0,-5:   188743679
Size Disk 0,-6:   18874367      MB
Size Disk 0,-7:   1887436
Press any key to continue . . .
```

`"Size Disk"` and `"Size Disk 0,-1"` are the same. It should not be.

Comment: Can you inform the code, cause for me %SizeDisk:~0,6% and %FreeS:~0,6% results in 6 digits likke it should.....

Comment: @RicardoBohner Thanks for response. That is the code that I am trying to get to work. I run it basically like that except just echo %SizeDisk% and %FreeS% to see values. Code should truncate last six digits, but it only truncates last 5.

If I use `FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3" %%s IN (DIR Z:\ /-C /-O /W) DO (SET FREE_SPACE=%%s)` / `SET /A FREE_SPACE=%FREE_SPACE:~0,-6%` that works fine though. I'd rather pull it from WMIC than use a hacky version with DIR. (But backquotes around the DIR Z:\ command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: The wmic command must be returning extra spaces or linebreaks, to remove them use a double for:

```
@echo off

for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %%x in (`wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='Z:'" get Size /format:value`) do for /f "Delims=" %%y in ("%%~x") do set SizeDisk=%%~y

for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %%x in (`wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='Z:'" get FreeSpace /format:value`) do for /f "Delims=" %%y in ("%%~x") do set FreeS=%%~y


echo Disk Size: "%SizeDisk%" Bytes
echo Free Space "%FreeS%" Bytes
echo.
echo Disk Size: "%SizeDisk:~0,-6%" Mega Bytes
echo Free Space "%FreeS:~0,-6%" Mega Bytes
echo.
pause
```

Comment: What is the point of the /A when you are simply truncating a string?  I see no math expression here.  Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: @Señor CMasMas: The Topic Creator explains the set /a as: "I also need these as integer values so I can do some basic math which is the reason for the /A." so I guess in his original script he does some calculations with the value....

Comment: /a does nothing but treat variables for math.  In this case, it is pointless. And thank you for answering this q for the asker.  I don't mean to criticize. :)

Comment: Thank you! See my edit in my main post. It's still not working right. I grabbed the size and then showed what happens as I truncate it one by one. The raw `SizeDisk` variable is same as `%SizeDisk:~0,-1%` where it shouldn't be. The code I posted in the edit is the exact code I ran.

And yes, thanks, I thought /A would set the variable as an integer but /A is only needed when doing the math, so I will eliminate that.

Comment: I think I got something wrong in your question, I thought that U would like to cut of everything except 6 digits from the left (~0,6) but instead you want to cut 6 digits from the right (~0,-6). My mistake. I think there is an extra digit returning from the wmic command like a {linebreak} thus when U use (~0,-6) it only removes 5 digits from the number + the {linebreak} totalizing 6 characters. To remove extra spaces & linebreaks from the wmic comand you have to use a double For. I'm editing my Answer....

Comment: @RicardoBohner Thank you very much! This works! I thought it might be a phantom character of some sort. Just strange though because if you add text to the end of the variable it shows up directly next to the output, no space or carriage return. For example `SizeDisk=%%xbytes` would output `1234567891234bytes` not `1234567891234 bytes`. You'd think there would be a space or line return if it was an actual character in the wmic output. What exactly does the `%%~x` and `%%~y` do to eliminate spaces? Either way, thank you very much.

Comment: %%~y only removes quotes from the replacement variable, but a second for ignores spaces and everything that comes after the text.

Comment: @RicardoBohner Thanks for the explanation. I knew about the quotes but didn't realize second FOR loop would eliminate spaces. Thank you again.